# Data loss when loop-mounting a file on removable USB storage

Tags: mount, usb

If I plug in a USB and modify files and unplug it I don't lose data. However if I use `mount` on a file on the USB I WILL lose data. What's with that? Is there anything I can do to prevent loss of data? It's weird that I can write a file and pull my usb out w/o loss of data but when using mount I will lose data. Here's the example

```
echo "Data Data Data" > /media/your-usb/data
#unplug your usb. plug into another computer
#you'll see you didn't lose any data

#Create a file, put ext4 filesystem on it
dd if=/dev/zero of='/media/your-usb/test.bin' count=100000;
losetup /dev/loop0 /media/your-usb/test.bin
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0
losetup -d /dev/loop0

#Mount FS
mkdir m
mount -o loop /media/your-usb/test.bin m

echo Test > m/test
umount m
#No loss of data

mount -o loop ./test.bin m
echo Test2 > m/test2
#wait a moment. You'd think the data will  flush

#unplug your USB
umount m
#plug your USB
mount -o loop ./test.bin m
cat m/test2 #error test2 is not a file
```

Comment: You've got the order mixed up... 1. Create mount point at `/mnt` 2. Mount Device. 3. Make Filesystem on mount point 3. Create file on New Filesystem, which is mounted at `/mnt` 4. Unmount Device 5. Unplug USB.  If I read the post right the step you lose data in, you're unplugging before you unmount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Linux detects a removable drive, it's smart enough to know that it should flush the data frequently. When you're mounting a loopback, it doesn't know that the backing device is a file which could be removed at any time.

You can force the system to not cache writes using:

```
mount -o loop,sync /media/your-usb/test.bin m
```

This will result in slower performance, and also note this warning about wear and tear from the `man mount` page:

```
   sync   All  I/O to the filesystem should be done synchronously. In case
          of media with limited number of write cycles  (e.g.  some  flash
          drives) "sync" may cause life-cycle shortening.
```

An alternative would be to at least run `sync` before removing the device if you don't want to `umount` for some reason.

Comment: I can't upvote but sync makes it work as expected. Thanks. Although the comments near ext3 and ext4 confuse me. It made it sound like it would flush in 5seconds and 15ms https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4288edfa0abf32e01eb3

Answer (score 1):

> If I plug in a USB and modify files and unplug it I don't lose data.

Correction: you haven't lost data *yet*. That you've noticed.

Presumably you, your distribution or the maintainer of the automounting program that you use has configured removable USB storage devices to be mounted with the `sync` option, which causes data to be written out immediately. The `sync` option has the advantage of writing out all data so that it isn't lost if the storage medium is pulled out suddenly or the system crashes, but it has many downsides:

- Flash-type storage will wear out sooner, because the data is written a few bytes at a time but the storage can only be updated by writing fairly large blocks each time, so each block ends up being rewritten many times. This can kill basic USB drives quickly.
- A filesystem that isn't unmounted properly will be marked as dirty. You can't distinguish a filesystem that was marked as dirty but contains consistent data from one that was pulled out in the middle of a write and contains inconsistent data. This doesn't apply to filesystems like FAT which don't have a “dirty” indicator.
- It's slower — potentially a lot slower.

Don't use `sync`. Unmount your devices before unplugging them.